# Почему выбрасывается исключение?

Tags: c++, исключения, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#define NOMINMAX
#include <limits>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
void delay(double delaySec) {
    clock_t delayClock = delaySec * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    clock_t start = clock();
    while (clock() - start < delayClock);
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char ch;
    double delaySec;
    string phrase;
    cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);
    do {
        cout << "Введите время задержки в секундах: ";
        try {
            cin >> delaySec;
        }
        catch (istream::failure exp) {
            cout << "Введите число!\n";
            cin >> delaySec;
        }
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Введите фразу: ";
        getline(cin, phrase);
        delay(delaySec);
        cout << "Фраза: " << phrase << endl;
    } while (delaySec != 0);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести не число, то выводится строка "Введите число", а потом выбрасывается исключение в строке `cin >> delaySec` в блоке catch:

**Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x74EAAA12 в Delay2.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::ios_base::failure по адресу памяти 0x005BEB14**
Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: `cin >> delaySec;` внутри обработчика исключений тоже может выбросить исключение, и на этот раз оно будет необработанным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется, выбрасывается.

- Во-первых, когда в процессе первого `cin >> delaySec` возникла ошибка и в потоке `cin` выставился флаг `failbit`, сам по себе этот флаг сбрасываться не будет. Поток `cin` переходит в перманентное ошибочное состояние. Вывести его из этого состояния, т.е. очистить флаги ошибок, можете только вы явным образом, например через вызов `cin.clear()`.

  Если поток находится в режиме выбрасывания исключений по каким-то флагам (как в вашем примере), то пока эти флаги не сброшены, все попытки чтения из данного потока будут мгновенно выбрасывать исключения, независимо от того, правильные данные вы подадите на вход или неправильные.

  Вы флаг `failbit` нигде не сбрасываете. Поэтому в вашем случае второй `cin >> delaySec` не будет даже пытаться ничего читать из потока, а вместо этого сразу же снова выбросит fail-исключение, которые вы не ловите. Его вы и видите.
- Во-вторых, даже если вы сделаете `cin.clear()`, вам все равно еще нужно убрать из входного потока ошибочные входные данные. Если вы этого не сделаете, то вторая попытка `cin >> delaySec` будет пытаться читать все тот же неправильный вход. В результате опять произойдет та же самая ошибка и выбросится то же самое исключение.

  Я вижу, вы вставили в код чистку буфера от неправильного ввода

  ```
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  ```

  но попытку повторного чтения `cin >> delaySec` вы делаете еще **до** чистки буфера. Должно быть наоборот: чистить буфер нужно **до** повторной попытки чтения. (А `cin.clear()` нужно сделать **до** `cin.ignore()`.)

Comment: прежде чем понять Ваш ответ мне пришлось почитать несколько статей на английском, поэтому долго я никак не реагировал) Теперь вроде бы всё более менее ясно. Но в одной статье http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/parallel/pgi/doc/pgC++_lib/stdlibug/err_7848.htm я наткнулся на информацию, что флаг ios_base::eofbit устанавливается всегда, когда я ввожу число или строку. У меня это не укладывается в голове, и кажется, что на сайте просто ошиблись. Можете сказать правда это или нет?

Comment: @JustLearn На сайте все написано правильно, не недостаточно хорошо объяснено. "Конец входной последовательности", из-за которого происходит выставление флага `eofbit`, есть, например, у файла на диске. У файла на диске есть четкий конечный размер. Если ваш входной поток ассоциирован с файлом на диске и при чтении этого файла вы упретесь в конец файла, то произойдет выставление флага `eofbit`, именно так, как описано по ссылке. У вас же в вашем коде происходит чтение из стандартного входного потока `std::cin`. Этот поток тоже может быть ассоциирован с файлом.

Comment: И тогда в нем тоже будет выставляться `eofbit` при достижении конца файла. Но при "обычном" запуске программы поток `std::cin` ассоциируется с терминалом, с клавиатурным вводом. В таком случае он фактически выступает как *бесконечный* файл. В нем никогда не будет выставляться флаг `eofbit`. Всякий раз, когда данные во входном буфере заканчиваются, такой поток просто продолжает ждать новых данных. Он ждет их вечно, то есть он никогда не предполагает, что данные уже закончились. В таком случае можно вызвать возникновение ситуации EOF через системные соглашения (напр. нажать `Ctrl-D` в начале стр

Comment: Но без этого при чтении данных с клавиатурного ввода этого вы не будете получать `eofbit` вообще. По умолчанию стандартный вход `std::cin` ведет как бесконечный файл. Более того, при форматированном вводе чисел вы будете обычно заканчивать ввод нажатием клавиши `Enter`. Это нажатие будет помещать во входной поток символ `\n`. Именно этот символ в потоке будет приводить к завершению чтения данных функцией форматированного ввода (напр. `cin >> delaySec`), т.е. фактически эти функции вообще не должны "упираться" в конец потока. Они будут останавливаться перед ним - на вашем `\n`.

Comment: огромнейшее спасибо за такое детальное объяснение!!!))

Comment: но можете помочь еще с одним вопросом?

Comment: Когда я ввожу данные с помощью cin он при нажатии `Enter` оставляет в буфере `\n`. И последующие вызовы `cin.get()` и `cin.getline()` не будут работать без очистки буфера от `\n` с помощью `cin.ignore()`, но при этом если вместо `cin.get()` или `cin.getline()` снова ввести данные с помощью `cin`, то все будет работать. Почему? Я никак не могу это понять. Гуглю уже два дня и на русском и на английском, а ответ на этот вопрос не могу найти  :(

Comment: `cin.get()` и `cin.getline()`натыкаются на символ `\n`, оставленный `cin` и сразу прекращают работу. А почему следующие вызовы `cin` работают без очистки буфера от `\n`?

Comment: @JustLearn: Все функции форматированного ввода начинают свою работу с того, что пропускают все пробельные символы, содержащиеся во входном потоке (пробел, табуляция, `\n` и т.п). И только после этого производят фактическое чтение форматированных данных, до тех пор пока не встретят какой-то "неправильный" символ. Поэтому функциям форматированного ввода не мешает оставшийся в буфере `\n` - они его сразу же пропускают. А вот `getline` ничего не пропускает.

Comment: огромное спасибо!) Несколько дней рыл интернет и не мог найти ответ.